# Stopping supervisord: Shut down

Tags: supervisord

I tired to start supervisor but getting error. Can anyone help? Thanks

/etc/init.d/supervisord file.

```
SUPERVISORD=/usr/local/bin/supervisord
SUPERVISORCTL=/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl
case $1 in
start)
        echo -n "Starting supervisord: "
        $SUPERVISORD
        echo
        ;;
stop)
        echo -n "Stopping supervisord: "
        $SUPERVISORCTL shutdown
        echo
        ;;
restart)
        echo -n "Stopping supervisord: "
        $SUPERVISORCTL shutdown
        echo
        echo -n "Starting supervisord: "
        $SUPERVISORD
        echo
        ;;
esac
```

Then run these

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/supervisord
sudo update-rc.d supervisord defaults
sudo /etc/init.d/supervisord start
```

And getting this:

```
Stopping supervisord: Shut down

Starting supervisord: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:286: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.
For help, use /usr/local/bin/supervisord -h
```

Conf file (located at `/etc/supervisord.conf`):

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10          ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info               ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:myproject]
command=/home/richard/envs/myproject_stage/bin/python /home/richard/webapps/myproject/manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8002 --log-file=/tmp/myproject_stage_gunicorn.log
directory=/home/richard/webapps/myproject/
user=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/myproject_stage_supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

Comment: Are you 100% certain there are no other `supervisord.conf` files around? As the warning states, it'll look in the current directory too, and in the local (relative to the current directory) `etc/` path, as well as relative to the `supervisord` executable. Use `-c` to be certain what configuration file is used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I search the file with `sudo find / -iname 'supervisord.conf'` and only found this `/etc/supervisord.conf`.

Comment: Good, that's that option eliminated; you still really want to use `-c` to prevent a local `supervisord.conf` from being picked up. Does your `supervisord` config work when started by hand?

Comment: What was wrong? Perhaps you can add an answer below if you think it could help future visitors?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry what do you mean started by hand?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I enter my mistake. Its not solved yet.

Comment: I meant run `supervisord -c /etc/supervisor.conf` from the command line, what happens then?

Comment: Oh, and there are [ready-made init scripts](https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts) available for `supervisord` to save you the hassle of writing your own.

Answer (score 75):

first of all, type this on your console or terminal

```
ps -ef | grep supervisord
```

You will get some pid of supervisord just like these

> root      2641 12938  0 04:52 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto  supervisord
>
> root     29646     1  0 04:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/supervisord

if you get output like that, your pid is the second one. then if you want to shut down your supervisord you can do this

```
kill -s SIGTERM 29646
```

hope it helpful. ref: http://supervisord.org/running.html#signals

Answer (score 48):

```
sudo unlink /tmp/supervisor.sock
```

This *.sock* file is defined in `/etc/supervisord.conf`'s [**unix_http_server**]'s file config value (default is /tmp/supervisor.sock).

Comment: `unlink: cannot unlink '/tmp/supervisor.sock': No such file or directory`

Comment: find / -name supervisor.sock 
It may sit here too. ./var/run/supervisor.sock

Comment: @Richard From your supervisord.conf file, It is supposed to be in /tmp/supervisor.sock

Comment: this didn't solve the problem, it's not making any sense we have to unlink to stop the supervisor.

Comment: Any ideas what the root cause is here? I only recently started noticing this when restarting supervisord from running chef-client. Sure, removing this socket might allow supervisord to restart, but why was it left in place to begin with?

Comment: Why doesn't supervisor terminate with an error code to allow scripts to unlink automatically and retry?

Answer (score 20):

```
$ ps aux | grep supervisor
alexamil         54253   0.0  0.0  2506960   6440   ??  Ss   10:09PM   0:00.26 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c supervisord.conf
```

so we can use:

```
$ pkill -f supervisord  # kill it
```

Comment: I learned that killing the demon should only be the very last resort, I suggest to consider using `sudo systemctl stop supervisor` instead.

Answer (score 19):

This is what works for me. Run the following in the Terminal (For Linux machines)

To check if the process is running:

```
sudo systemctl status supervisor
```

To stop the process:

```
sudo systemctl stop supervisor
```

Answer (score 16):

Try running these commands

```
sudo unlink /run/supervisor.sock
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/supervisor start
```

Answer (score 6):

As of version `3.0a11`, you could do this one-liner:

`sudo kill -s SIGTERM $(sudo supervisorctl pid)` which hops on the back of the `supervisorctl pid` function.

Comment: I'm on centos7. `supervisorctl pid` return the pid, but `$(supervisorctl pid)` display `command not found`.

Comment: Have you tried something like `\`supervisorctl pid\`` instead? `$()` is just a way of returning the output of another command within the same command line. I'm not sure if Centos7 would have this, but I'd be scratching my head if it didn't. In any case if you can't do my one-liner above, just separate it out to two commands instead.

Answer (score 4):

There are many answers already available. I shall present a **cleaner way** to shut down supervisord.

supervisord by default, creates a file named **supervisord.pid** in the directory where supervisord.conf file exists. That file consists the pid of the supervisord daemon. Read the pid from the file and kill the supervisord process.

However, you can configure where the supervisord.pid file should be created. Refer this link to configure it, http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

Comment: is there any way to get this id and place it in a command line instruction? something like: kill | cat supervisor.pid

Comment: based on Jonathan's answer, this works for me: kill $(cat supervisord.pid)